# How to select a single list element when using map in React to alter the state value

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I'm super new to React and building my first ever app which is a url shortening app. Each shortened url has a button next to it whose text is set to 'copy' initially and once the user click on it the link is copied to the clipboard and the button text changes to 'copied'. Everything is working fine except if I have multiple shortened url's and I click on one of the buttons next to any particular url, it still only copies that url to clipboard but the button text changes to copied on all of them.
If anyone can please enlighten me how to single out those buttons individually that'll be of great help. I've tried using the id but maybe I'm not doing that correctly?

P.S - this is first time I'm posting on here so apologies upfront if I missed any crucial bits.

```
import {useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

function Main() {
    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [list, setList] = useState(initialList);
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    const handleAdd = async () => {
        const res = await axios.get(`https://api.shrtco.de/v2/shorten?url=${name}`)
        const {data: {result: {full_short_link: shortLink}}} = res 
        const newList = list.concat({name:shortLink, id: uuidv4()});
        setList(newList);
        setName('');
      }
    const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState("Copy");

return (

    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" 
        value= {name} 
        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        placeholder='Shorten a link here'
        onClick = {()=> setButtonText('copy')}
        />
        <button onClick = {handleAdd}>Shorten it!</button>
        </form>
            
        <ul>
            {list.map((item, index) => (
            <li key={item.id}>{item.name}<button 
            onClick = {() => { navigator.clipboard.writeText(item.name); setButtonText("Copied")}} >
            {buttonText}
            </button></li>))}
        </ul>

export default Main``
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s because you are using one state variable for all of your buttons, you need a variable to keep track of state for each individual button.  You should refactor the code within your map function into its own component, and declare the buttonText state within that component.  That way each button has its’ own state.

Eg (sorry for the capitalisations in my code):

MyButton.js

```
Const MyButton = ({item}) => {
  const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState(‘Copy’)

  Return (
    <li key={item.id}>{item.name}
      <button 
        onClick = {() => { 
          navigator.clipboard.writeText(item.name); 
          setButtonText("Copied")}
        } 
      >
        {buttonText}
      </button>
    </li>
)
Export default MyButton
```

Form:

```
// ……

<ul>
 {list.map((item, index) => <MyButton key={item.id} item={item} />)}
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Coot3, Thanks for your answer so promptly. is there any way that it can be done within the same component i.e. declaring state for each button. or does it have to be a separate component?

Comment: You certainly could (using an object i.e. to hold your values, like `{ [id]: buttonText }`), but in React you should often try to break things down into the smallest possible elements and then build more complex elements from those. Have a look here (if you haven't already): https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html